# Vue ProxyTable does not work in axios

Tags: vue.js, cross-domain, frontend, axios

I'am doing an end-to-end separation project, and my back end is completed.
Now I met the cross domain problem

My Vue code:

```
// config/index.js
proxyTable: {
    "/api":{
        target: "http://localhost:8001",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        pathRewrite:{
            "^/api":"/api"
        }
    }

this.$axios.get("/api/user/login?username=xx&password=123")
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

if I visit `http://localhost:8001/api/user/login?username=xx&password=123`in my browser, it returns the JSON I wrote.

But it don't work in axios,the error says `GET http://localhost:8085/api/user/login?username=xx&password=123 504 (Gateway Timeout)`.

Comment: maybe it's a CORS issue, check your network tab to see the error for that request in your chrome/firefox console.

Comment: the error says` Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:8085/api/user/login?username=xx&password=123`

Comment: don't check the console, check the network tab

Comment: the state code is 504 Gateway Timeout ,the response is Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:8085/api/user/login?username=xx&password=123

Comment: I meant check your browsers console, open it go to `network` tab and click on `response` tab

Comment: yeah,the response in network tab is Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:8085/api/user/login?username=xx&password=123

Comment: hmm.. I thought it should've been more descriptive. have you checked this https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html yet? I had the same exact issue at first didn't solve it.

Comment: yes, l have checked it. But l have no idea where is the mistake

Answer (score 1):

may be you will get a first hint with the debug option enabled:

```
logLevel: 'debug'
```

If you npm run dev in your terminal, you should see a note, that the proxy table is used, while starting the server.

```
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]
```

Later, running your app, you should see the called proxy route, e.g.

```
[HPM] GET /static/api/returnReasons/returnReasons.php -> http://vuetools:8888
```

I also run in some problem with using proxy, but this was not due to axios:
[webpack proxyTable is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164047/proxy-table-stopped-working)

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Solved by replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 !

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem CORS. You need a crossdomain request.
Configure your web server: 

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`

Also you can customize the headers directly into the axios, passing them through the parameters:

`headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},`

I had a similar problem, but I don't get result, although the documentation of the axiosis says that this is the right solution.